# export directory listing with all folders, subfolders and files with file size, modification time in an excel sheet 2010 on windows

Tags: windows, excel, cmd

I need to create a table in this format:

```
FOLDER NAME     MODIFICATION TIME   FILE SIZE      FILE NAME
Nexus           5/14/2015 16:56       <DIR>          pictures
                                     0 bytes    

Nexus\pictures  4/22/2015 10:53     155,466,275      auto
                5/4/2015 10:13       2,006,176       ship
                4/21/2015 11:01       <DIR>          june
                5/14/2015 15:17       <DIR>           july
                                    157,472,451
```

I tried using this code in excel visual basic window but since I am not familiar with vb scripting I am unable to edit it to fit my required columns. Please help me edit this code:

Place this code in a Standard module

VB:

```
Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS As Long = &H1 ''' For finding a folder to start document searching
Const BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN As Long = &H2 ''' Does not include network folders below the domain level in the tree view control
Const BIF_RETURNFSANCESTORS As Long = &H8 ''' Returns only file system ancestors.
Const BIF_BROWSEFORCOMPUTER As Long = &H1000 ''' Returns only computers.
Const BIF_BROWSEFORPRINTER As Long = &H2000 ''' Returns only printers.
Const BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES As Long = &H4000 ''' Returns everything.

Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260 



Type BROWSEINFO 
    hOwner     As Long 
    pidlRoot   As Long 
    pszDisplayName As String 
    lpszINSTRUCTIONS As String 
    ulFlags    As Long 
    lpfn       As Long 
    lParam     As Long 
    iImage     As Long 
End Type 

Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDListA Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszBuffer As String) As Long 
Declare Function SHBrowseForFolderA Lib "shell32.dll" (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) As Long 


Function BrowseFolder() As String 

    Const szINSTRUCTIONS As String = "Choose the folder to use for this operation." & vbNullChar 

    Dim uBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO 
    Dim szBuffer As String 
    Dim lID    As Long 
    Dim lRet   As Long 

    With uBrowseInfo 
        .hOwner = 0 
        .pidlRoot = 0 
        .pszDisplayName = String$(MAX_PATH, vbNullChar) 
        .lpszINSTRUCTIONS = szINSTRUCTIONS 
        .ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS 
        .lpfn = 0 
    End With 

    szBuffer = String$(MAX_PATH, vbNullChar) 

     ''' Show the browse dialog.
    lID = SHBrowseForFolderA(uBrowseInfo) 

    If lID Then 
         ''' Retrieve the path string.
        lRet = SHGetPathFromIDListA(lID, szBuffer) 
    If lRet Then BrowseFolder = Left$(szBuffer, InStr(szBuffer, vbNullChar) - 1) 
    End If 

End Function
```

In a second Module copy this code

```
VB:
Option Explicit 

Sub CreateList() 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Workbooks.Add ' create a new workbook for the folder list
     ' add headers
    With Cells(1, 1) 
        .Value = "Folder contents:" 
        .Font.Bold = True 
        .Font.Size = 12 
    End With 
    Cells(3, 1).Value = "Folder Path:" 
    Cells(3, 2).Value = "Folder Name:" 
    Cells(3, 3).Value = "Size:" 
    Cells(3, 4).Value = "Subfolders:" 
    Cells(3, 5).Value = "Files:" 
    Cells(3, 6).Value = "Short Name:" 
    Cells(3, 7).Value = "Short Path:" 
    Range("A3:G3").Font.Bold = True 
    ListFolders BrowseFolder, True 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub 

Sub ListFolders(SourceFolderName As String, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean) 
     ' lists information about the folders in SourceFolder
    Dim FSO    As Scripting.FileSystemObject 
    Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder, SubFolder As Scripting.Folder 
    Dim r      As Long 
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject 
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName) 
     ' display folder properties
    r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
    Cells(r, 1).Value = SourceFolder.Path 
    Cells(r, 2).Value = SourceFolder.Name 
    Cells(r, 3).Value = SourceFolder.Size 
    Cells(r, 4).Value = SourceFolder.SubFolders.Count 
    Cells(r, 5).Value = SourceFolder.Files.Count 
    Cells(r, 6).Value = SourceFolder.ShortName 
    Cells(r, 7).Value = SourceFolder.ShortPath 
    If IncludeSubfolders Then 
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders 
            ListFolders SubFolder.Path, True 
        Next SubFolder 
        Set SubFolder = Nothing 
    End If 
    Columns("A:G").AutoFit 
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing 
    Set FSO = Nothing 
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
```

End Sub

NOTE: This code uses Microsoft Scripting Runtime. The macro examples need a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library. You can do this from within the VBE by selecting the menu Tools > References and scroll for Microsoft Scripting Runtime, check th box then click OK

Comment: You need to explain what you've already tried, and what problems you ran into.   Include any code you have, even if it's not working.

Comment: I tried this vba script but I am not that familiar with coding so not able to make the required changes:

Answer (score 0):

You can get a directory listing into a text file with the > symbol.

For example, "DIR >test.txt" will output the results of the DIR command to a text file that you could then pull into excel.

I could not get the DIR command to output anything close to your format above, but this may be a start if you can get something useful.

Comment: hey thanks. I actually found out that we can code it in vba script and run the script in excel to get the output however, I cannot code in vba so I am stuck, trying to find out.